# why does PREPARE statement not respect INDEXing

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-performance

Help me understand as to why query evaluated using prepared statement does not respect indexing.

```
\d+ lerg;

                                                        Table "public.lerg"
   Column   |            Type             |                     Modifiers                     | Storage  | Stats target | Description
------------+-----------------------------+---------------------------------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id         | bigint                      | not null default nextval('lerg_id_seq'::regclass) | plain    |              |
 lata       | character varying           | not null                                          | extended |              |
 npa        | character varying(3)        |                                                   | extended |              |
 nxx        | character varying(3)        |                                                   | extended |              |
 block      | character varying(1)        |                                                   | extended |              |
 ocn        | character varying           |                                                   | extended |              |
 created_at | timestamp without time zone | not null default now()                            | plain    |              |
Indexes:
    "lerg_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "lerg_npa_nxx_block" UNIQUE, btree (npa, nxx, block)
```

Total number of record in the `LERG` table.

```
select count(*) from lerg; 
=> 199846
```

The prepared statement

```
   prepare fetch_lata(char(3), char(3), char(1)) as select lata from lerg where npa=$1 and nxx=$2 and block=$3;
```

execute statement.

```
    explain analyze execute fetch_lata('365','406','A');
                                                     QUERY PLAN
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on lerg  (cost=0.00..5163.31 rows=1 width=6) (actual time=0.014..27.530 rows=1 loops=1)
   Filter: (((npa)::bpchar = '365'::bpchar) AND ((nxx)::bpchar = '406'::bpchar) AND ((block)::bpchar = 'A'::bpchar))
   Rows Removed by Filter: 199845
 Execution time: 27.560 ms
(4 rows)
```

Not able to understand.

- Why the table scan?
- Why is indexes not used?

On other note.

```
explain analyze select lata from lerg where npa='365' and nxx='406' and block='A';
                                                       QUERY PLAN
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Index Scan using lerg_npa_nxx_block on lerg  (cost=0.42..8.44 rows=1 width=6) (actual time=0.016..0.016 rows=1 loops=1)
   Index Cond: (((npa)::text = '365'::text) AND ((nxx)::text = '406'::text) AND ((block)::text = 'A'::text))
 Planning time: 0.081 ms
 Execution time: 0.033 ms
(4 rows)
```

**Q.** A `select` query with proper indexing beats hands down the prepared statement query, why ?

**Q.** Are there no advantage of using `PREPARED` statement for simple query like the above.

Just a head's up the difference for query 10_000 record was so high that I have to give up on prepared statement.

The result of query 10_000 record.

```
                                   user      system      total      real
pg_without_prepared_statmt        0.050000   0.080000   0.130000 (  0.935051)

pg_with_prepared_statmt           0.090000   0.110000   0.200000 (  5.707693)
```

Machine details.

```
Postgres Version : 9.5.9 
Mac OS: 10.12.5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the parameters for your prepared statement are of type `character` (the same as `bpchar`), so the equality operator for that type is used, and the index cannot be used because it is defined with `character varying`.

If you change the arguments of the prepared statement to `varchar`, it should work as expected.